# GTFS - How to draw routes on a map (Leaflet + sql DB)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gtfs

I am making a bus management system (school project) and  I'm having trouble with drawing routes on a map (**Leaflet**).

Right now I have a **sql** database of **gtfs** **data**. In order to draw routes I dynamically create a geojson that contains the various coordinates of the *shapes* table and then just connect those points using leaflet. The result is a mess with lines that connect points with no criteria and order. I suppose it's a problem with the sql query to the db. So here are my questions:

Which tables are necessary to draw a route? (*shapes*? *stops*? both? others?)?

What's the query to extract the coordinates I need in the right order to be drawn correctly?

Is there a better way to do this?

Here's an image to illustrate the problem better (it's just a representation of the issue because I don't have access to the project right now): [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssw4e.png)

Comment: You could use the [Leafet Routing Machine](https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/basic-usage/) for this. Then, from your DB, you would get the origin and the destination coordinates, and let the LRM do the rest. If you're interested in providing your own waypoints I guess you could create a `routes` table, a `waypoints` table, and then a `routesxwaypoints table`, which would connect specific waypoints into a route. The table would also have an `INT` order column, to determine the order of the waypoints.